# Asynchronously and continuously parse file in Python

Tags: python, asynchronous

I am looking to parse a log produced by an external program. This log is parsed into a list which is then served to a front-end application.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638472/continuously-parse-file-in-python) questions covers how to continuously read a file; however, my application needs to be doing other things the `time.sleep(1)` period.

Ideally, I would be able to call a function, say `parse_log(log_list)`, and have the results of the parsing be appended to `log_list`. Additionally, I should be able to clear `log_list` outside of the parser without breaking anything.

Bonus challenge: Functionality to pause and resume parsing.

Edit: Preferably cross-platform.

Comment: nowait I/O (e.g. the `select` system call in Linux instead of `sleep`) or perhaps inotify

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45626/output-file-contents-while-they-change

Comment: I can't find the first and I'm not clear on how to use Pyinotify to achieve what I asked.